# where did the "AndroidHelper.ShowAndroidToastMessage("msg...", false);" Method migrate to?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Tango: Unity: (Fermat) where did this method migrate to?

```
AndroidHelper.ShowAndroidToastMessage("msg...", false);
```

It was present pre-Fermat but is now no-longer there... was very nice way to send notifications to user that were more subtle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a regression in the unitypackage, it has been fixed. Try download and re-import the package again.